# Find words with specified first letter (Regex)

Tags: c#, regex, words

I need regex to find words starting, for example, whith letters "B" or "b". In sentence `Bword abword bword` I need to find `Bword` and `bword`.
My curresnt regex is: `[Bb]\w+` (first character is space), but it doesn't find `Bword`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using following regex: `(?i)\bB\w*\b`

It means:

1. `(?i)` - turn on ignore case option
2. `\b` - first or last character in a word
3. `B`
4. `\w*` - Alphanumeric, any number of repetitions
5. `\b` - first or last character in a word

So it will find `Bword` and `bword`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the word boundary pattern `\b` to match boundaries between words or start/end:

```
\b[Bb]\w*\b
```

Comment: It works too, but I have less than 15 points, so I can't upvote :-(

Answer (score 0):

The pattern for that should be - **"[Bb]\w+"**

You need to escape the backslashes (with another backslash) in a regular expression. \b --> \b